# How to spread the parameters of a previous instance of a class constructor to another instance

Tags: javascript, constructor, spread-syntax, class-constructors

I would like to ask what I am doing wrong here

**My goal**

I want to create instances from a class constructor.
The first is gonna be a more generic class called Person and then another that will inherit properties from that class.

**My question is**
When all classes are set and the first instance that points to the Person constructor is declared, how could the pass the `key: values` of the previous instance to the next instance since I don't want to repeat my self over the same arguments.

**I am currently** spreading the previous parameters of the instance but obviously, I am doing something wrong.

```
class Person {
    constructor (name,yearOfBirth,job) {
        this.name = name;
        this.yearOfBirth = yearOfBirth;
        this.job = job;
    }
    getAge() {
        return new Date().getFullYear() - this.yearOfBirth
    }
    greet(){
        return `${this.name} is a ${this.getAge()} years old ${this.job}`
    }
}

class footballPlayer extends Person {
    constructor(name,yearOfBirth, job, team, cups) {
        super(name, yearOfBirth, job)
        this.team = team;
        this.cups = cups;
    }
    cupsWon() {
        console.log(`${this.name} who was bord on ${this.year} and works as a ${this.job} won ${this.cups} with ${this.team}`);
    }
}

const vagg = new Person('vaggelis', 1990, 'Developer');
const vaggA= new footballPlayer( {...vagg} , 'real madrid', 4)

console.log(vagg.greet());
console.log(vaggA.cupsWon());
```

Thank you!

Comment: You cannot spread an object into an arguments *list*. You should make a constructor that takes an object instead.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you want to do, you need to pass only the values of the parameters that describe the `Person` to the `footballPlayer` (note: class names should by convention be uppercase).

```
var vaggA = new footballPlayer( ...Object.values(vagg) , 'real madrid', 4);
```

**Edit**: In case you fear a different order with `Object.values` (which is a [real threat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30076219/does-es6-introduce-a-well-defined-order-of-enumeration-for-object-properties/30919039#30919039)), you can create a getter function in the `Person` class that will return the exact list of parameters in the order they are supposed to be given to the constructor:

```
class Person {
  // ...
  describe() {
    return [this.name, this.yearOfBirth, this.job];
  }
}

const vaggA = new footballPlayer( ...vagg.describe() , 'real madrid', 4);
```

Comment: `Object.values` [does not guarantee order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30919039/1048572), so this might easily break

Comment: That's not true regarding `String` keys [in 2018](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31102605/2898738). This can be discussed but no need to downvote IMO.

Comment: Unfortunately the answer you linked is simply wrong. See the one I linked with quotes from the specification

Comment: Your link tells the same about String keys: "Other string keys (if applicable), in property creation order."

Comment: Yes, but that property is guaranteed only for `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` etc, *not* for `Object.keys`, `Object.values` and `Object.entries`.

Comment: Btw, even if they were in property creation order, this approach is far too fragile as it breaks when the constructor implementation changes.

Comment: I've edited my answer to take into account your statements. Thanks for having me get aware of this.